# what service can i use for cheap storage?

Tags: storage

I thought of using amazon S3 and EBS but it doesnt appear to allow http(s), ftp(s) or ssh which are protocols git can use.

Essentially i want a service i can use to store my private git repository. Access for others via http would be nice or a linux box where i manage users/permissions is good too. I am using my own VPS at the moment but i HD space is limited.

What can i use?

Answer (score 2):

Why not setup an actual linux server on Amazon's ec2 service? it can access the EBS and S3 storage backends, and serve the data out over http, ssh, rsync, whatever...
In fact, they have a [free trial](http://aws.amazon.com/free/) of their EC2 and EBS services right now, with their micro server instance and 10GB of space.

Answer (score 1):

Github offers cheap paid accounts for hosting private repositories: https://github.com/plans

Comment: Thats insanely expensive depending on the situation. Its cheaper to use that but if your on lan and have a local comp used as dedicated  server and all you need is to push and you (have a) serveradmin then setting up your own mirror is a lot cheaper. Especially when you have >20ppl